# Regex search, instead of findall

Tags: python, regex

i am new to regular expressions when it comes to Python. The problem i struggle with is to specific data from a binary file. When i use the regex findall i can get all the data i want from the regex, but i want to try to use the search instead. When i run the search i only got a few data from the binary file. When i look at the output i only got out for example 110e13xxxxxx, and not data from 110d12xxxx pattern.

```
import re

count = 0

with open("data.bin", "rb") as f:
     lines = f.readlines()

for l in lines:
    l = l.hex()

    match = re.search(r'(11)(0d|0e)(12|13)(.{12})(.{2})', l)

    if match:
        print(match.groups())
```

Comment: `re.search` only looks for 1 match. What do you need to achieve here? Why not use `re.finditer` to get all matches and keep the groups?

Comment: When i use re.finditer i got the wrong offsets from it.. and i dont really know why :/

Comment: *This question was marked as an exact duplicate of an existing question.* is not actually true to life: this question is just unclear. @IamnoobatSQL, if you manage to explain what you mean in the question update, with exact input text you have and expected output, and if that is not already explained on SO, I am sure your question will most likely be reopened.